# C# Combobox and DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I've got a combobox which retrieve data from a select and a datagridview which retrieve data from another query. I would like to filter the datagridview using the comboboxvalue. I am trying everything but nothing work. Could you please help? Moreover, why when I declare dataview=((DataTable)datagridview.datasource.defaultview (first row in combobox_SelectedIndexChanged ) I can't see any values in the combobox anymore, instead I see System Data DataRowView but the first question is more important for me

```
    private void Form5_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=xxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxx;Integrated Security=True;");
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("  SELECT id, customername+' - '+cast(inserted as varchar(19)) as targ FROM bf where customername>'a' order by customername asc, inserted desc ", conn);
        SqlDataReader reader;

        reader = sc.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("targ", typeof(string));
        dt.Load(reader);


        comboBox1.ValueMember = "id";
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "targ";
        comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
        conn.Close();


        var select = "SELECT [id],[CustomerName[email],[Capital] FROM baf order by id desc";
        var c = new SqlConnection("Data Source=xxxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxx;Integrated Security=True;"); // Your Connection String here
        var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(select, c);

        var commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
        var ds = new DataSet();
        dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
        dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //var dataView = ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).DefaultView;

        //    if (comboBox1.Text == "Remove filter")
        //    {
        //        dataView.RowFilter = string.Empty;
        //    }
        //    else
        //    {
        //        //dataView.RowFilter = "id = {comboBox1.Text}";
        //    }

        //}

    }
```

Comment: Trying in this way: private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            DataView dv = dataGridView1.DataSource as DataView;
            dv.RowFilter="id=[ComboBox1.Text]"; give me the error Object reference not set to an instance of an object. And shows System Data DataRowView in the combobox

Comment: If you are trying to use string interpolation on the RowFilter you need to prepend a dollar sign: `$"id = {comboBox1.Text}"`
However, you should probably use `SelectedValue`, not `Text`.

Comment: private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged

                                var dataView = ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).DefaultView; 

                if (comboBox1.Text == "Remove filter")
                {
                    dataView.RowFilter = string.Empty;
                }
                else
                {
                    dataView.RowFilter = $"id = {comboBox1.SelectedValue}";
                }
Error unexpected character, plus only assignment call, increment, decrement and new object can be used as statement, Invalid expression term ''


        }

Comment: What version of Visual studio? If you are not doing string interpolation then you have to take the combobox property access out of the quotes.

Comment: VS 2010 professional. What do you mean in taking the property access out of the quote?

Comment: Using this code:  var dataView = ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).DefaultView;

                if (comboBox1.Text == "Remove filter")
                {
                    dataView.RowFilter = string.Empty;
                }
                else
                {
                    dataView.RowFilter = "id ="+comboBox1.SelectedItem;
                }                                                                                                       I've got the problem that I retrieve System.Data.Data.RowsView in the combobox.

Comment: Ok, you can't use string interpolation with VS 2010. I mean something like this : `"id = '" + comboBox1.Text + "'"`
However, you have a number of problems. Does `baf.id` really match up with `bf.targ`? Your SQL is invalid: `...[CustomerName[Email]...`. You don't need or use the CommandBuilder. You don't Dispose any of your disposable resources. These are reasons nobody is answering your question, there are 5 or 6 questions here.

Comment: Understand. I am a beginner. However about the SQL I just cut the original one, I am a SQL developer so don't concern about that. I thought was going to be easy to resolve the matter for specialist like you. No idea where is the command builder you are talking about in my code. Neither the disposal. As I commented before it looks I am very close but I must resolve/understand why the combobox retrieve System.Data.Data.RowsView

Comment: I can't see why that is happening from your code, but it usually means you have lost your `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` properties and the combo box is simply calling `ToString()` on what it contains - which is `System.Data.Data.RowsView`

Comment: That's the point. No one understand why this happens but it is the crucial point.

Answer (score 1):

You need to properly use BindingSource for the purpose. Below is the complete working example. To experiment with it what you need is as under:

1. Create a blank form Q1
2. Add one DataGridView control and one ComboBox control to the form
3. Copy paste below code into Q1.cs file
4. Run and experiment

I hope this will get you going nicely.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinFormQ
{
    public partial class Q1 : Form
    {
        public Q1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        BindingSource bs;

        private void Q1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=xxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxx;Integrated Security=True;");
            // conn.Open();
            // SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("  SELECT id, customername+' - '+cast(inserted as varchar(19)) as targ FROM bf where customername>'a' order by customername asc, inserted desc ", conn);
            // SqlDataReader reader;
            // 
            // reader = sc.ExecuteReader();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("targ", typeof(string));
            // dt.Load(reader);

            dt.Rows.Add("1", "Targ-1");  // example code - remove
            dt.Rows.Add("2", "Targ-2");  // example code - remove
            dt.Rows.Add("3", "Targ-3");  // example code - remove
            dt.Rows.Add("4", "Targ-4");  // example code - remove

            comboBox1.ValueMember = "id";
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "targ";
            comboBox1.DataSource = dt;

            // var select = "SELECT [id],[CustomerName[email],[Capital] FROM baf order by id desc";
            // var c = new SqlConnection("Data Source=xxxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxx;Integrated Security=True;");  Your Connection String here
            // var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(select, c);

            // var commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable bf = new DataTable("BF");
            bf.Columns.Add("id", typeof(string));  // example code - remove
            bf.Columns.Add("CustomerName", typeof(string));  // example code - remove
            bf.Columns.Add("Email", typeof(string));  // example code - remove
            bf.Columns.Add("Capital", typeof(string));  // example code - remove

            ds.Tables.Add(bf);
            bs = new BindingSource(ds, "BF");
            // dataAdapter.Fill(bf);

            bf.Rows.Add("1", "Customer-1", "Email-1", "Capital-1");  // example code - remove
            bf.Rows.Add("1", "Customer-2", "Email-2", "Capital-1");  // example code - remove
            bf.Rows.Add("2", "Customer-3", "Email-3", "Capital-2");  // example code - remove
            bf.Rows.Add("3", "Customer-4", "Email-4", "Capital-3");  // example code - remove
            bf.Rows.Add("3", "Customer-5", "Email-5", "Capital-3");  // example code - remove
            bf.Rows.Add("3", "Customer-6", "Email-6", "Capital-3");  // example code - remove
            bf.Rows.Add("4", "Customer-7", "Email-7", "Capital-4");  // example code - remove
            dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;

            this.comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
        }

        void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (comboBox1.Text == "Remove filter")
            {
                bs.RemoveFilter();
            }
            else if (comboBox1.SelectedValue == null)
            {
                bs.RemoveFilter();
            }
            else
            {
                bs.Filter = "id = " + comboBox1.SelectedValue;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks indeed Rupesh but where should I put the BindingSource bs; ? I did put after Public Partial class but using your code I retrieve Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource' to type 'System.Data.DataTable'.

Comment: Declare `BindingSource bs;` just before Form5_Loan() method. Regarding cast issue I would like to know which line of code produces this error?

Comment: I did change the BindingSource bs position, still System.Data.Systemdatarows in my combo, plus error Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource' to type 'System.Data.DataTable'. in the line   75:           var dataView = ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).DefaultView;

Comment: I have modified my answer and put the working example, if that could help have elegant solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved in this way (maybe not the most elegant but it does work):

```
    private void Form5_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=xxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxx;Integrated Security=True;");
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("  SELECT id, customername+' - '+cast(inserted as varchar(19)) as targ FROM baf where customername>'a' order by customername asc, inserted desc ", conn);
        SqlDataReader reader;

        reader = sc.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("targ", typeof(string));
        dt.Load(reader);


        comboBox1.ValueMember = "id";
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "targ";
        comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
        conn.Close();



        var select = "SELECT [id],[CustomerName], [email],[CapActual] FROM baf order by id desc";
        var c = new SqlConnection("Data Source=xxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxx;Integrated Security=True;"); // Your Connection String here
        var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(select, c);

        var commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
        var ds = new DataSet();
        var bf = new DataTable("BF");
        ds.Tables.Add(bf);

        dataAdapter.Fill(bf);
        dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bf;






    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        var select = "SELECT [id],[CustomerName],[email],[CapActual] FROM baf where id="+comboBox1.SelectedValue+" order by id desc";
        var c = new SqlConnection("Data Source=xxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxxx;Integrated Security=True;"); // Your Connection String here
        var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(select,c);

        var commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
        var ds = new DataSet();
        var bf = new DataTable("BF");
        ds.Tables.Add(bf);

        dataAdapter.Fill(bf);
        dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bf;










    }

    }




    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For the viewers who are interested in finding how to make the code in question work successfully, I present the solution below. To achieve readiness to experiment, the data is hard coded which need be modified as per actual situation.

```
    DataView dataView = null; // <<< Difference #1

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("targ", typeof(string));

        dt.Rows.Add("1", "Targ-1");  // example code - remove
        dt.Rows.Add("2", "Targ-2");  // example code - remove
        dt.Rows.Add("3", "Targ-3");  // example code - remove
        dt.Rows.Add("4", "Targ-4");  // example code - remove

        comboBox1.ValueMember = "id";
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "targ";
        comboBox1.DataSource = dt;

        var bf = new DataTable("BF");
        bf.Columns.Add("id", typeof(string));  // example code - remove
        bf.Columns.Add("CustomerName", typeof(string));  // example code - remove
        bf.Columns.Add("Email", typeof(string));  // example code - remove
        bf.Columns.Add("Capital", typeof(string));  // example code - remove

        bf.Rows.Add("1", "Customer-1", "Email-1", "Capital-1");  // example code - remove
        bf.Rows.Add("1", "Customer-2", "Email-2", "Capital-1");  // example code - remove
        bf.Rows.Add("2", "Customer-3", "Email-3", "Capital-2");  // example code - remove
        bf.Rows.Add("3", "Customer-4", "Email-4", "Capital-3");  // example code - remove
        bf.Rows.Add("3", "Customer-5", "Email-5", "Capital-3");  // example code - remove
        bf.Rows.Add("3", "Customer-6", "Email-6", "Capital-3");  // example code - remove
        bf.Rows.Add("4", "Customer-7", "Email-7", "Capital-4");  // example code - remove
        dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bf;

        dataView = bf.DefaultView;  // <<< Difference #2
        this.comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);  // <<< Difference #3
    }

    void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.Text == "Remove filter")
        {
            dataView.RowFilter = string.Empty;
        }
        else
        {
            dataView.RowFilter = string.Format("id = '{0}'", comboBox1.SelectedValue);   //  <<< Difference #4
        }

    }
```